# Padding between 2 columns with affect padding elsewhere

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a row with 2 columns. Between there 2 columns there is a padding on 30px. I need that to be 10px. See a live example on bootply.com [here](https://www.bootply.com/FK66DUhzOy).

In the core bootstrap, the class "col-sm-4" has a `padding-left` and `padding-right` set to 15px, so therefore 30px. The problem for me now, is that I need to keep the 15 px on the left and right side of the columns.

How can I make the padding smaller between the 2 columns, without it is affecting the padding on the left and right side?

[image: Padding between columns]

```
<style type="text/css">
    .row > div{
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .sidebar{
        background: #dbdfe5;
    }
    .content{
        background: #b4bac0;
    }
    .sidebar, .content{
        min-height: 300px;
    }
</style>

<body style="background-color: #4940fb;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="sidebar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why not just overwrite the padding-right for the col-sm-4 to 7.5px and the padding-left for the col-sm-8 to 7.5px?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It is very important that it is gonna be the best possible solution. The page there has to use the column setup is gonna be visited of many many many people each day. Would your suggestion be the best way to solve the problem?

Comment: If you're asking for "the best" way than you're asking for opinionated answers. This is something SO wants to avoid

Comment: This will 100% solve the problem for your case, however, you want to be careful as overwriting Bootstrap classes on a large website might affect other pages/sections.If you can, you want to add some extra classes to your divs(something like col-sm-4 and small-right-padding and col-sm-8 and small-left-padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the padding-right for the col-sm-4 to 7.5px and the padding-left for the col-sm-8 to 7.5px.

[Here](https://codepen.io/florinsimion/pen/XBWoRG) is a codepen example.

However, you want to be careful as overwriting Bootstrap classes on a large website may affect other pages/sections. If you can, you want to add some extra classes to your divs(something like col-sm-4 and small-right-padding and col-sm-8 and small-left-padding).

so you can have these rules:

```
.small-padding-left {
    padding-left:7.5px;
  }

  .small-padding-right {
    padding-right:7.5px;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer I appreciate your time. I can feel I actually feel better on making my own classes for this. I tried to look at your updated bootply, but I cannot see any changes in the code, or is it just me?

Comment: if you are going to mess with the Bootstrap `.col` left and right paddings then remember you have to also update the `.row`'s negative left and right margins as well

Comment: Sorry. I've updated my answer. Never used bootply.com before.

Comment: Hm I just cannot see how that is not removing the padding from the sites. Do you have time to throw the code in a jsfiddle or something else? I just tried it now, but seems to remove the padding on the left side of the column

Comment: You can check my updated answer with a working codepen https://codepen.io/florinsimion/pen/XBWoRG

Comment: That solves the problem very beautifully. Thank you a lot for your time.